# Better way to determine which shell is being used at runtime (Windows)?

Tags: c++, windows, runtime

I have a function that clears a terminal screen. It's supposed to work on Windows and any *nix based OS. If the function detects that the caller's OS is Windows, it will check to see if the caller is using `cmd.exe` or something else (`git-bash` or `cygwin`).

Is there a better way to do this? I don't like the fact that I need to rely on the HOME variable.

Compiler: `g++`

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>

void clearScreen() {
  #ifdef _WIN32
    if (std::getenv("HOME"))   // git-bash & cygwin home var is called HOME
        std::system("clear");  // cmd's home var is called HOMEPATH
    else
        std::system("cls");
  #else
    // Assume POSIX
    std::system("clear");
  #endif
}
```

**NOTE**: This function has been tested in `cmd.exe`, `git-bash`, and `WSL`. It has not been tested in `Cygwin`.

Comment: You can detect that a Cygwin-based application is being built at compile time.  For Windows applications, perhaps call CreateProcess or ShellExecuteEx rather than system()?  That ought to make it independent of the parent shell.  Or in principle you could use the API, e.g., FillConsoleOutputCharacter and friends.

Comment: @HarryJohnston the point of the function is to issue the correct shell command based on the shell in use. Only the OS is relevant at compile time.

Comment: Regarding Cygwin, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21267670/886887).  Whether you wind up on the `_WIN32` branch or the `POSIX` branch will depend on the version of Cygwin and/or the build settings, so it may be preferable to test for Cygwin explicitly.

Comment: I guess you could check the value of the `COMSPEC` environment variable, that's what determines which shell the system() command will use.  (But I think this will be a fragile solution no matter what you do.)

Comment: (Caveat: I don't know how Cygwin implements `system`, it might not work the same way as Microsoft's C runtime.)